# Filtering Array of Objects Returns Empty Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, web, server

I am trying to filter all objects in the projects array that are not in the savedProjects array but the result is an empty array. Am I filtering the wrong way?

My code:

```
router.post('/get-related', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
try {
    const projects = await Projects.find({researchers: req.body.fullname});
    let savedProjects = await Projects.find({projectID: req.body.projectsIDs});
    projects.filter(p => savedProjects.includes(p) === false);
    res.json(projects);
} catch (err) { 
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ message: err }) };
});
```

Comment: `savedProjects.some(p)` p is not a function and you need to pass a function in a `some()`

Comment: It would help if you can explain what you expect it to do. What are you trying to achieve with `savedProjects.some(p) === false`?

Comment: I am trying to filter objects from the projects array that are not in the saved projects array.

Comment: `filter()` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the array in place.

Comment: Related: [toUpperCase() is not making the string upper case](/q/15326582/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the $nin specification fixed it. I imported the saved projects and then queried all projects that did not include the ones in the savvedProjects array.

```
router.post('/get-related', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const savedProjects = await Projects.find({projectID: req.body.projectsIDs});
    let IDs = savedProjects.map(p => p.projectID);
    const projects = await Projects.find({ category: req.body.researcharea,  projectID: { $nin: IDs }});
    res.json(projects);
} catch (err) { res.json({ message: err }) };
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Array filter function returns a new array without modifying the original so for this to work I think something like this would be enough:

`let filteredProjects = projects.filter(p => savedProjects.includes(p) === false);  res.json(filteredProjects);`

more info here, [MDN Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score -1):

const suggestedProjects = projects.filter(p => savedProjects.some((p)=> p=== false);